# UTF8 characters allegedly changed in NetBeans diff when using GIT

Tags: git, netbeans, utf-8, diff

Pictures say all:

[image: Graphical diff on a file]

[image: Textual diff on a file]

The problem is that the method's comments didn't really change, but diff shows that they did on UTF8 characters.

I'm using NetBeans IDE 7.2 (Build 201207171143), OS X 10.8 (12A269), git 1.7.9.6 (Apple Git-31.1).

Comment: That diff looks to me like the munged characters were already in the index. It's the `+` diff that reads correctly, yes?

Comment: This happens to me as well. I take any file with non-ascii characters and do a git diff. At this point everything is ok, empty diff. Then I make any change to the file and save it, and do a git diff again. Now, instead of only highlihting the change, it also shows the weird stuff MacDada is seeing, so as if the old file somehow changed (there were valid charaters when i made the first diff and looked at it). Note: i'm on Windows 7, NetBeans IDE 7.2 (Build 201207171143), Netbeans project is set up as UTF-8.